# UIDocumentInteractionController crashes caught by Exception Breakpoint

Tags: objective-c, ios, exception, breakpoints, uidocumentinteraction

I am using the UIDocumentInteractionController to preview pdf files.  I display the controller as follows:

```
self.docInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:pdfUrl];
    self.docInteractionController.delegate = self;
    self.docInteractionController.name = literature.title;
    [self.docInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
```

It all works a treat.  However, if I add an Exception Breakpoint catch-all to Xcode and debug the app then I notice quite a few crashes happening as I interact with the pdf document.  The app does not crash totally, but the exception breakpoint fires whenever I tap on the document.

Do I need to worry about this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not retaining the UIDocumentInteractionController Object thats when you will see a crash. Try to retain self.docInteractionController. I too ran into the same problem and this fixed it.